# Why -[NSView setLayer: nil] is called by AppKit?

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nsview, appkit

I have a layer backed view with sublayers. It is a part of a larger view. This larger view is removed and added back to some view hierarchy.

When I remove this larger view from its superview, the layer backed view loses the backing layer and therefore all sublayers. So when I add all this back, it doesn't look like it should (layers are missing).

I found that `-[NSView setLayer: nil]` is called by AppKit when `-[NSView removeFromSuperview]` called:

```
  * frame #0: 0x00000001228b4ba4 ***`***::setLayer(self=0x0000000104aa1830, cmd="setLayer:", layer=0x0000000000000000) at ****
    frame #1: 0x00007fff84506244 AppKit`-[NSView _setWindow:] + 755
    frame #2: 0x00007fff86a31a52 CoreFoundation`__53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 114
    frame #3: 0x00007fff86a318e6 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 198
    frame #4: 0x00007fff84da12a7 AppKit`__21-[NSView _setWindow:]_block_invoke.643 + 151
    frame #5: 0x00007fff84506ae6 AppKit`-[NSView _setWindow:] + 2965
    frame #6: 0x00007fff84509587 AppKit`-[NSView removeFromSuperview] + 465
```

Any idea why AppKit would do this? Is there a way to avoid this?

I can override `-[NSView setLayer:]` and not assign nil layer there but it doesn't look like a good solution.

UPD: I checked the code of `-[NSView _setWindow:]` and it seems to be related to `NSViewKeepLayersAround` preference. Googling it does not help.

```
0x7fff84506211 <+704>:  leaq   0x1ccdc4e8(%rip), %rdi    ; @"NSViewKeepLayersAround"
0x7fff84506218 <+711>:  leaq   0x1cf972e4(%rip), %rdx    ; sNSViewKeepLayersAroundComputedValue
0x7fff8450621f <+718>:  leaq   0x381f3(%rip), %rcx       ; NSViewKeepLayersAroundDefaultValueFunction
0x7fff84506226 <+725>:  movl   $0x1, %esi
0x7fff8450622b <+730>:  callq  0x7fff844e3706            ; _NSGetBoolAppConfig
0x7fff84506230 <+735>:  testb  %al, %al
0x7fff84506232 <+737>:  jne    0x7fff84506244            ; <+755>
0x7fff84506234 <+739>:  movq   0x1cf46c4d(%rip), %rsi    ; "_removeLayerIfOwnedByAppKit"
0x7fff8450623b <+746>:  movq   %r14, %rdi
0x7fff8450623e <+749>:  callq  *0x1cc50f14(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff9b8b7040: objc_msgSend
```

Comment: Is there simple sample source you can put somewhere to test. I can't seem to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. My code works as a VST plugin in host application. I do not know how this host application setups window and content view. At first I blamed application but from stack trace it is clear that it's a feature of AppKit.

Comment: Is your view really a "layer backed view" or is it a "layer hosting view"? You're not supposed to muck with the layer of a layer backed view, including adding sublayers. You don't own that layer and AppKit is free to do what it wants with it.

Comment: I tried both. In both cases the root layer is removed by AppKit. The reason is not poor management but some intended behavior controlled by "NSViewKeepLayersAround" application option.